# Set of points to set of points proximity algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, distance, proximity

I have two sets of 3D points and I want to find the closest point in the second set for each point in the first set. In a more difficult case, the sets may have different numbers of points, and I need to find the closest pairs of points. I'm not sure what this problem is called, but I have some brute-force ideas for solving it. For example, I could calculate the distance between all pairs of points and choose the pairs with the shortest total distance. The maximum number of points in each set is 20, so I don't need the most efficient solution.

Comment: "Nearest neighbour"

Comment: Though if N <= 20 here, are you sure that the brute force approach (likely the simplest code) is insufficient?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth surely two sets of 20 points would still result in a huge number of possibilities if you wanted to just check them all?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Thanks Oliver, I came up with Nearest Neighbor problem in my searches, but couldn't find an article that points to this problem.

Comment: @m69 I am afraid you are right :(

Comment: Maybe the "stable marriage" algorithm, with distance as preference? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem

Comment: 20*20 = 400.  Not huge by most standards.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Wouldn't that be 19*18*17...?

Comment: If it is what it seems to be, then for two small sets of points you are better off simply calculating the distances to each point of the other set. No need to overcomplicate things. Use the distance squared for comparisons for efficiency.

Comment: @m69 - I don't think so.  For each point in set A, compute the distance from each point in set B, and pick the minimum.  So N * N.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Does that guarantee an optimal solution in any way? Ax + By may be the best choice for Ax, but not for By.

Comment: You probably need to describe what you mean by "optimal" - you haven't mentioned any optimality criterion in your question, beyond finding the closest match for each element.

Comment: @m69 Stable Marriage Problem seems a good start.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Are you sure about it being N*N, it seems it is N!

Comment: Why do you think it is N! ?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I think the optimal solution is when the paths connecting the closest points do not intersect!?? I am not sure how to describe it!

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Sorry you are right it is N2

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I think the optimal solution is when the paths connecting the closest points do not intersect!?? I am not sure how to describe it!

Comment: Do both sets have the same number of points? Do you need a one-to-one mapping where each point in each set is only paired with one other point from the other set? Is it OK for all points from set 1 to map to the same point in set 2?

Comment: @AlexisOlson The number of points can be different. There is a one-to-one mapping.

Comment: If set 1 has more points than set 2, then a one-to-one mapping is not possible.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Each point will be associated with only one point. Some will remain though!

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I didn't understand fully what you said but come on be nice, it is really hard to describe this question! :D

Comment: Well, do you need a solution, a good solution, or the optimal solution? And how do you define good and optimal? Is the objective to minimize the sum of the distance between all pairs?